# Wordpress wp_list_pages: list parent page siblings

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get this working for quite a while now. I get close but can't find a working solution.

My page structure is like this:

```
1 FIRST LEVEL
  2 SECOND LEVEL
    3 THIRD LEVEL
      4 CAR
         5 SUV
         5 MINIVAN
         5 FULLSIZE
      4 MOTORCYCLE
      4 BICYCLE
  2 SECOND LEVEL
  2 SECOND LEVEL
1 FIRST LEVEL
```

I need a wp_list_pages statement that does the following: on 4th and 5th level pages (and ONLY on those) the navigation lists all 4th level pages.

(When i'm on page "CAR" the navigation should be CAR,MOTORCYCLE,BICYCLE. And also when i'm on page MINIVAN the navigation should be CAR,MOTORCYCLE,BICYCLE.)

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Have you made all these specific pages?  or are they posts? just making sure (I know you said 4th level pages).  Does this happen in all themes?

Comment: These are pages. But I think you misunderstood me. I'm looking for a wp_list_pages statement that does what I described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
if (count($ancestors) >= 3) {
    $parent = $ancestors[2]; // third level page ID
    wp_list_pages('depth=1&child_of=' . $parent);
}
```

Feel free to ask if you're unsure of anything :)

Comment: Man, that's perfect! I had to modify it a bit, so 4th and 5th level show the 4th level pages. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code i finally used, thanks to TheDeadMedic's answer. (I canceled one page level so it's for 3rd and 4th level)

```
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
if (count($ancestors) == 2) {
   $parent = $ancestors[0];
}
elseif (count($ancestors) == 3) {
   $parent = $ancestors[1];
}

if ($parent) { 
   $tabs = wp_list_pages('depth=1&child_of=' . $parent);
}
```